# Method inherited from different module uses import that fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, scikit-learn

I tried to create a scikit-like classifier in module `my_classifier`. As such, I made the classifier class to inherit the folowing class from scikit.base:

```
class ClassifierMixin(object):
    def score(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        from .metrics import accuracy_score
        return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

However, when I call `MyClassifier.score(X,y)`, I get the following error

```
--> 290         from .metrics import accuracy_score
ImportError: No module named metrics
```

What I think is happening is that the "." in `.metrics` causes Python to search for `metrics` in `my_classifier` instead of `sklearn`. Am I getting this right?

Is there some way to fix this from the outside of sklearn? I know I can easily define the method in my class, but using inheritance seems "better"<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: Why are you doing the import *inside* the method? It should be at the top of your script with all of the other imports, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: The import is done in scikit module https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b/sklearn/base.py#L267, I do not have control over this code.

Comment: Oh! Interesting, I've no idea why they've done it like that.

Comment: Could it be an oversight?

Comment: I really don't know. I would consider raising this as [an issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues) on the GitHub repo, if it's not there already.

Comment: Oh ok, I will do that then.

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to import a module before it is used, in case the method never gets called. If it is called, it can access the names inside the method.

Comment: The ``.metrics`` import is a *relative import*, meaning that it will import a file within the package where it is called. I suspect you're using ``from .metrics import accuracy_score`` in your own module, and should be using ``from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score``. Could you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error, and include the full traceback?

Comment: Note: OP opened a github issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5554).

Comment: Thank you, the problem is gone now after reinstalling the modules involved. I do not know what was the cause. Many thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: @jakevdp i looked for 'metrics' in the module where I defined MyClassifier class and there was none. However, in the notebook where I ran into problem, I had at one point imported 'metrics' from another unrelated module. However, I can not reproduce the error anymore.